# Clear all model fields before validation in FireFox and IE10

Tags: java, jsp, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow and I have a problem with binding fields from spring form to my model.
So I have a model:

```
   public class MyModel implements Serializable {
private long senderAccountId;
private String senderId = "";

private String documentId = "";
private String performDateView = ""
   //......
  }
```

And in jsp I have:

```
            <portlet:actionURL var="actionURL" portletMode="view">
                   <portlet:param name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
           </portlet:actionURL>

        <form:form id="creationForm" modelAttribute="payment" action="${actionURL}"
            method="post">

     <form:input path="senderId" size="18"/>
      //............
```

And in I in my webflow xml:

```
          //....
         <transition on="saveAsDraft" to="decisionActionResult" validate="true">
         //......
```

In IE10 and FireFox:
When I in validation object my all model fields are cleared out and setted to null.
But in Google Chrome evresing work fine. Is it only my problem ?

Comment: You don't need to add the tags to the title. I removed them for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in this:  $('form').submit();
Must be: $('#form').submit(); and add id to form, that is all, but in Google Chrome it worked fine!